# Avoiding zoomout for this.map.fitBounds()

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

How can i avoid zoomout on this.map.fitBounds()?
Doing this.map.fitBounds will zoom in or zoom out map for fitting bound values. I want to avoid zoomout functionality for fitBounds. How i can do like that?

**Tried Following.This will execute after executing fitBounds(). Need to execute before executing fitBounds()**

```
var lineBounds = this._trail.getLineBounds()
 , current_zoom = this.map.getZoom()
 , center = this.map.getCenter();

 this.map.fitBounds(lineBounds, {
    padding: [29, 29],
 });

this.map.once('zoomend', function() {
   if (current_zoom > this.map.getZoom()) {
      this.map.setView(center, current_zoom);
   }
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the `minZoom` option your map instance. Problem is that you'll manually need to edit the options object of your map instance. The `setMinZoom` and `setMaxZoom` methods have been introduced in Leaflet v1.0.0-beta.2 and Mapbox isn't using that version yet. Otherwise you could simply do `map.setMinZoom(number)`, now you'll have to resort to `map.options.minZoom = number`. So after fitting your bounds, get the map's current zoomfactor using `map.getZoom` method and set that factor value as your `minZoom` option.